# include template tag not working in django

Tags: django

My Views.py files looks like below

```py
def homepage(request):
    template = 'homepage.html'
    list_display_template = 'list.html'
    list = model.objects.all()

    return render_to_response(
        template,
        {'list_display_template': list_display_template, 'list' : list,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

And my homepage.html looks like below:-

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main_content %}
    {% include list_display_template %}
{% endblock %}
```

And my list_display_template (list.html) has following information

```
<div class= "span10">
{% for item in list %}
    <p> {{ item }}</p>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The above works fine in development, but in production the include tag is not working and when i inspect the element, it is not showing any items from list.html. could someone help with this.

Edit :- My folder structure is as below

```
project_name/
    project_name/
         settings.py
    static/
       css/
       images/
    templates/
      homepage.html
      list.html
      base.html
```

Thanks

Comment: If you do `{% include 'list.html' %}` in your `homepage.html` it should work.

Comment: Does `{% include "list.html" %}` work?

Comment: Nope. both the above does not work. I tried giving full pathname 'templates/list.html'...even that does not work

Comment: That is the issue - template is not pointing to a valid location. what is the location of your 'list.html' file ?

Comment: I have edited my question with my folder structure.

Comment: i have created the project again from scratch and it works fine now. Not sure what happened before.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Turns out my homepage.html was not where I expected. It was actually loading a completely different file in a different location, which wasn't including anything, and so I wasn't seeing any changes and incorreclty interpreted this to mean the include wasn't working. Deleting your project may have fixed a template directory location problem or deleted a duplicate homepage.html that might have been causing a similar problem.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem,but i will answer this question in a way that other users with a similar problem can understand.

you probably have a template block of some kind in the included html file,
this block either is expecting an include of some kind or is causing an error of which  is calling exception that django passes and therefore you are not able to see the error,
if you use `{% load someLoad %}` in the parent template then use it in the included html too,
i guess this changes from version to version.

in my (very specific) case i had this missing in the included html file:

```
{% load i18n %} 
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
```

Comment: that's it, a missing load i18n in the included template... Ockham never fails.

Comment: I just had a similar problem and almost went crazy because of it. what made it more complicated is that it only happened on the production server and not on my machine. later, I found out that that navigation bar which I used 'include' on it had urls that I didn't slugify so that caused a lot of errors but they were silenced by the include statement.
Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 13):

Another situation where an **include** statement will fail without raising an error is if you are working in a template which extends another, and your **include** is outside of a named **block**:

```
{% extends "my_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% include "partials/file1.html" %}
{% endblock %}

{% include "partials/file2.html" %}
```

In this case file2.html will not be included because it is not in a block, and you will get no warning messages, and will try all sorts of things before you realise what you've done :-)

Comment: This is indeed a bad situation. It applies of course to all kinds of tags you put outside the {% block %} area. They may not evaluate.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot in 2021. This ("this" = "includes that process data need to be inside the `{%block %}` declaration") should probably be clearer in the documentation.

Comment: @DavidRhoden I am glad this helped you. I wonder if this is something the template parser could actually detect and warn about.

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar problem. I was able to diagnose it by temporarily copying and pasting the html (i.e, navigation.html) that I wanted to include directly into the parent page (base.html). It seems that if there are errors in the included html, it just doesn't get read in and no errors appear.

With the code from navigation.html pasted into base.html I got a 500 error because one of the named urls in navigation.html had no reverse.

Comment: Very valuable suggestion. TLDR: move the included part to the main template and look for errors.

Answer (score 3):

If there is any issue/ error with the include template, django by default won't show the error. You can enable it using the setting variable `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True` Then you will able to view the error in the template when you try to load that page.

In the above case there may be some load tag is missing `{% load xxx %}` in the included template.

Comment: In Django 1.8 and later, you should set `TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["debug"]` to `True` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to mess with `template tags`, `load` and `include` options, there is another way to do this:

> render the template explicitly with your parameter, store it as a string, then render into the main template as a context.

```py
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
```

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx['loader'] = render_to_string('common/loader.html', {'loader': randint(0, 15)})
        return ctx
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue, and i try all the method upon. But still have no include the "html". Then, i try to move the "html" from the app/template to the project/template. it's worked. so i move the html file back, and add the  path in setting.py about the template path. it's solved. Even you didn't add the template path in setting.py, the pycharm still can link the "including file " to the exact place. and run the django project without error....it took me 3days...

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error because you wrote

```
{% include archivive_name %}
```

instead of

```
{% include 'archive_name.html' %}
```

which has the .html and the enclosing `''`