# Not able to load multiple blocks in base template in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I am having a problem in my templates. I am trying to add two blocks in the base template,
it works when I include them but when I try to extend the base template it won't work and won't even throw an error.

[image: image showing what's wrong refer line 17 and 18]

Comment: did you check the console for any errors ?

Comment: Yes but there was no error,.can you be more specific about what i should be looking for in console

Comment: anything related to the missing elements... please also post the contents of the included html and the extended page where you are not getting it

Answer (score 1):

This shud be the problem ...  I will also leave a link to the original answer

**MOVE THE INCLUDE BLOCKS INTO THE NAMED BLOCKS**

Another situation where an include statement will fail without raising an error is if you are working in a template which extends another, and your include is outside of a named block:

```
{% extends "my_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% include "partials/file1.html" %}
{% endblock %}

{% include "partials/file2.html" %}
```

In this case file2.html will not be included because it is not in a block, and you will get no warning messages, and will try all sorts of things before you realise what you've done.

[Include tags not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756590/8401179)

Comment: I am trying to extend my base template and using multiple blocks but django is only populating block content everything else is skipped

Comment: try including the templates with the full url path rather than the short one

Answer (score 0):

My Django ver: 2.2

For all trying to figure out how to declare multiple blocks, even though base has just one {% block content %},

You can declare block within block

This is my base.html:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my home.html:

```
{% block content %}
   {% extends 'base.html' %}
   Some common content I want
   {% block my_variable_data %}
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

My some other page:

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}
{% block data_content %}
{% endblock %}
```